# how many different key pair values in a json object using d3 or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have an array of objects which looks somewhat like this

```
 [ {
      "created_date" : "2013-08-12T06:25:00",
      "descriptor" : "Noise, Barking Dog (NR5)"
    },
    {
      "created_date" : "2013-08-17T06:25:00",
      "descriptor" : "Noise, Barking Dog (NR5)"
    },
    {
      "created_date" : "2013-08-17T02:25:00",
      "descriptor" : "Noise, Barking Dog (NR5)"
    },
    {
      "created_date" : "2013-08-12T06:25:00",
      "descriptor" : "Loud Music"
    },
    {
      "created_date" : "2013-08-17T06:25:00",
      "descriptor" : "Loud Music"
    },
    {
      "created_date" : "2013-08-17T02:25:00",
      "descriptor" : "Construction Noise"
    },
    {
      "created_date" : "2013-08-17T02:25:00",
      "descriptor" : "Construction Noise"
    }]
```

The question is how do I count how many "descriptor" categories are there and their name
How should I approach this using D3 or jquery. Basically the idea is to form different groups

Comment: That's not an object; that's a bunch of objects. Your question cannot be answered unless you show how those objects are collected.

Comment: @pointy--I added some edits. See if that helps

Comment: Or use Underscore: http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use d3's `d3.map()` to map each `descriptor` to the number of its occurrences.

```
var map = d3.map();
data.forEach(function(d) {
    var descriptorCount = map.get(d.descriptor);
    map.set(d.descriptor, descriptorCount === undefined ? 1 : ++descriptorCount);
});
console.log(map); // {Noise, Barking Dog (NR5): 3, Loud Music: 2, Construction Noise: 2}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dR2DQ/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var UniqueDescriptors = "";
for (var i =0; i<array.length;i++) {
    var obj = array[i];
    if (obj.descriptor && UniqueDescriptors.indexOf(obj.descriptor) == -1) {
        UniqueDescriptors += obj.descriptor + '|';
    }
}
// this returns just the number
//return (UniqueDescriptors.split('|').length - 1);
// this returns an array of the different descriptors if you need the names. you also can count the number by accessing the length property
return UniqueDescriptors.split('|').pop();
```

of course the obvious flaw of this script is that it assumes there are no pipes in the descriptor values.

Comment: don't use `for..in` on arrays! use the good ol' `for` loop or `Array#forEach`. `for..in` does not guarantee iteration order and it picks up non-numeric properites including polyfilled methods

Comment: May I ask why you chose to append every identifier to a string?

Comment: @FelixKling because then you can use the `String.indexOf` method to check against duplicates

Comment: You could also use `Array#indexOf` for that.

Comment: @FelixKling according to Mozilla Developer Network, `Array#indexOf` is not supported by IE 8 or less

Comment: I doubt `Array#forEach` is supported by IE8 or less. So if you use that method, you could use `Array#indexOf` as well.

Comment: changed to use a basic for loop

Comment: @Felix-- I am not too worried about ie 8. The final output would be a data mapping which probably wont run on ie.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the array and collect each descriptor:

```
var descriptors = (function(data) {
    var seen = {};
    data.forEach(function(obj) {
        seen[obj.descriptor] = true;
    });
    return Object.keys(seen);
}(data));
```

To get the number of unique descriptors, just take the length of the array:

```
descriptors.length
```

---

If you need to support older browser that don't support `Object.keys` or `Array#forEach`:

```
var descriptors = (function(data) {
    var seen = {};
    var descriptors = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
        var descriptor = data[i].descriptor;
        if (!seen[descriptor]) {
            descriptors.push(descriptor);
            seen[descriptor] = true;
        }
    }
    return descriptors;
}(data));
```